# Django URL path not matching

Tags: python, django

I am currently having a non-matching URL error for the following URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/report/?report=Report`. The questions/answers found here and elsewhere have been of no use. I have a button that I am trying to redirect with.

```
     report/ ?report=Report [name='candidate-report']

The current path, report/, didn't match any of these.
```

`project.urls`:

```
from django.urls import include, path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_view, name='home'),
    path('report/', include('Reports.urls'))
]
```

`Reports.urls`:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('?report=Report', views.candidate_report_view, name='candidate-report'),
]
```

`Reports.views`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import CandidateReportForm


def candidate_report_view(request):
    category_form = CandidateReportForm.category()
    comment_form = CandidateReportForm.comment()

    return render(request, 'candidate_report.html', {'category_form': category_form, 'comment_form': comment_form})
```

`base.html`:

```
        <form class="d-inline-block float-right" action="report/" method="get">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" id="report_button" name="report" type="submit" value="Report">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Reports/urls.py` file, you don't want to put the query string (the `?report=Report`) as part of the URL, because it's not part of the path; it's extra information.

You can just use:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # Included in project/urls.py in the way you provided, this will
    # resolve to simply '/report'.
    path('', views.candidate_report_view, name='candidate-report'),
]
```

Then in your `Reports/views.py` file, you can access the value of the `report` key in your query string by using:

`request.GET['report'] #Should give you the value 'Report', based on the HTML you shared.`

Comment: While the first half has given me progress, I am unsure as to what you mean in the second half. Could you clarify?

Comment: In a GET request, everything after `?` at the end of an URL is called a "query string." It takes the form `?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&...` When your form uses the "get" action like yours does, it puts the form data in the URL in a query string (your button is named `report` and it has a value of `Report`, which is why the URL it's going to is `/report/?report=Report`. Django can read query string values in views by doing `request.GET['key_name']` or `request.GET.get('key_name', 'some default value')`

Comment: Here's Django's documentation on the `QueryDict` object: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict